# Apache Spark Streaming Left Outer Join Output Records

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

We are working on Spark Streaming application where it sources data from kafka.We have producer which publishes data to kafka from a file which has 1.5 million records. Out of 1.5 million records, there are 1 million records of A type and 0.5 million records of B type. Here in this file we have 0.5 million records have same column value which will be used to join in Spark streaming.

So in spark streaming, we are doing left outer join of these two streams(A left outer join B). So output expected should have 1 million records( 0.5 million records which are inner join and 0.5 million records for null join from left stream).

However we have received different output count for different watermark:
1) If we provide watermark as 15 minutes, we do receive 0.5 million records(inner join) and 0.5 million records(unmatched records with null).

2) If we provide watermark as 2 minutes, we receive more than 1 million records (around 1.1 million records) where we found that output file has duplicate records (records which are part of inner join also appear as part of null join)

Please help me to understand why left outer join emitting more records when provided less time in watermark.

When i say more number records, i meant it emits records which are:
-> matched(0.5 million) + records which are unmatched( 0.5 million with null values from left stream) + 0.1 million records with null join from left stream.

The 0.1 million records are the extra records which are suprisingly already part of inner join (0.5 million) and still present with null join from left stream.